# role of gis in geotechnical engineering?

Tags: arcgis-10.0

Sir,
    i am a pg student and presently doing my project work in 'bore hole data management and analysis using GIS'.in this i created different layers of soils coming under my study area using arcGIS software,and developed a 3D soil model. but now i am little confused that wether my project divert from geotechnical engineering.heard that GIS is a tool to aid Geotech.i want to know is there any further applications in GIS which helps to modify my project

Answer (score 5):

GIS is extensively used in geotechnical engineering in very many different ways.  The example you give is a classic one, so I'm not sure why you are confused.  Other applications include 3D visualisation of geological formations. Shell an BP both have a number of top-end 3D suites in their offices where they can visualise wells and the planned steering of the drill head to avoid problematic formations (e.g. weak structures where a blow-out is a danger).  [Here's a link](http://www.exprodat.com/blogs/blog_Top-10-Reasons-to-Use-GIS-in-Oil-and-Gas-.htm) discussing the top ten uses of GIS in the oil industry (I'm focussing on that because it is a HUGE geo-tech industry and a massive consumer of GIS)

Although ArcGIS is [extensively used](http://www.esri.com/industries/petroleum) (and therefore QGIS, SAGA etc could also be used, and not forgetting [GRASS GIS' Voxel](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/raster3dintro.html) modelling for 3D rasters), the petroleum and associated geotech industries tend to use some proprietary GIS-style software.  There are a huge number of these products, many often closely associated with the companies which originally developed them e.g. Schlumberger's [Petrel](http://www.slb.com/services/software/geo/petrel.aspx?entry=ad_google_sis_petrel&gclid=CNa0p4HOz7gCFfLItAodHScA-Q) or [JewelSuite](http://www.bakerhughes.com/products-and-services/reservoir-development-services/reservoir-software/jewelsuite-reservoir-modeling-software) (BakerHughes) and you can get links to many more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geologic_modelling#Geologic_modelling_software).  That link also provides some links for ground water modelling too.

In fact, I can't imagine the modern geotech industry without some form of GIS!  Far from being a divertion from geotech, I would say it is a core solution whether you are using a geology modelling package aimed specifically at the geotech industry or a more general gis like ArcGIS or GRASS etc.